# Uncaught ReferenceError: Clipboard is not defined: when using clipboard.js with Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use 'clipboard.js' in my Rails 6 application to copy the current location to the clipboard for the user to paste into an email. My first attempt was to use 'clipboard-rails' but that didn't work so have tried manually.

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:-
----------------------------------------
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'clipboard', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>



app/javascript/packs/application.js:-
-------------------------------------
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("packs/clipboard")

var clipboard = new Clipboard('.clipboard-btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});


import "bootstrap"




app/views/bundles/show.html.erb:-
---------------------------------
<p class="link" id="bar"><%= "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}" %></p>
<button class="clipboard-btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

I keep getting **'Uncaught ReferenceError: Clipboard is not defined'** error in the browser console and pressing the button does nothing. I've tried 'Clipboard' and 'ClipboardJS'. I'm developing on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to assign the require to Clipboard:

```js
    const Clipboard = require("packs/clipboard");
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.clipboard-btn');
```

Comment: thank you, it got me further however I got another error. 


clipboard.js:474 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can show your entire code.

Comment: Not really. Since I raised the query I've subsequently found I didn't need the 'javascript_include_tag' in 'application.html.erb'. The code from the Gemfile is complete except for comments that have been removed. The only code not shown from the 'bundles/show.html.erb' is a table.

Comment: I found a useful answer [here](https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/javascript/copying-value-from-variable-to-clipboard/).